# What does "i.(string)" actually mean in golang syntax?

Tags: go, syntax, functional-programming

I recently started looking for functional go examples and I found this function:

```
mapper := func (i interface{}) interface{} {
    return strings.ToUpper(i.(string))
}
Map(mapper, New(“milu”, “rantanplan”))
//[“MILU”, “RANTANPLAN”]
```

Now in this function, as you can see the `return` value of mapper is:
`strings.ToUpper(i.(string))`.

But, what does this `i.(string)` syntax mean? I tried searching, but didn't find anything particularly useful.

Comment: When googling for punctuation, it helps to spell it out. I found the duplicate by searching "go dot parentheses".

Comment: @sepp2k oh okay. I'll use that next time. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`i.(string)` casts (or attempts at least) `i` (type `interface{}`) to type `string`. I say attempts because say `i` is an `int` instead, this will panic. If that doesn't sound great to you, then you could change the syntax to

```
x, ok := i.(string)
```

In this case if `i` is not a `string`, then `ok` will be `false` and the code won't panic.

Answer (score 2):

`i.(string)` means converting `i`(`interface{}` type) to `string` type.